# Redis keyspace notifications detect only newly created keys and not replaced

Tags: redis, py-redis

I am trying to be notified in redis when new key is created and not being notified when the key is updated/replaced. Is there a way to set notifications this way or is there any other way to be notified when only new key was created and not existing one got replaced? I am using hset to set the keys.

Comment: You can't, key space notification doesn't diff between SET call that creates and update.
Did you check RedisGears?